# Neo4j php: Unable to delete node through Cypher

Tags: neo4j

I am not able to delete a node using neo4php(using cypher api) .

Here is small code of mine:

```
$client = new Everyman\Neo4j\Client();
$queryString = "START n = node(*) return n";
$query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString);
$result = $query->getResultSet();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $id = $row['n']->getId();
    $deletequery = "START node = node(".$id.")" 
    ." Delete node";
    $query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $deletequery);
```

Comment: I got the answer , After deletion fetch result using $query->getResult () , then only nodes will be deleted.

Comment: If you found the solution, please answer your own question.

Comment: Yup, please post the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer . 
Actually after deleting the node , i have to fetch the result using $query->getResult